Subprocess Task Is not teriminating in the `@celery_app.task`
I would like to stop the celery task using the celery ID. I am executing the subprocess task to run the spider for scrapping. So, when we stop the celery task the sub-process task also terminates.
But actually the Subprocess task is not terminating. I use the os.kill(pid,signal) but it is not terminating and the celery tasks continues running in the docker celery- Container.
Celery_Worker
@celery_app.task(bind=True, name='jina_fetch_urls_celery_task', base=AbortableTask)
def jina_fetch_urls_celery_task(self, run_id: PydanticObjectId, site: str):
    try:
        for i in range(5):
            if self.is_aborted():
                return 'Task stopped!'
            logger.info(f"Progress: {i}")
            self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'progress': i})
            sleep(1)
        
        process = subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'base_spider', '-a', f'start_url={site}', '-a', f'task_id={str(run_id)}'], cwd='/code/jina_scrapy')
        
        # Save the subprocess ID in task metadata
        subprocess_id = process.pid
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'subprocess_id': subprocess_id})
        logger.info(f"Subprocess ID set in Celery: {subprocess_id}")
        process.wait()  # Wait for the subprocess to finish
        return {'status': 'DONE', 'subprocess_id': subprocess_id

Run/Endpoint:
@router.post("/{run_id}/stop", status_code=201)
async def stop_run(run_id: str = Path(..., title="The ID of the run to stop")) -> Any:
    run = await retrieve_run(run_id)
    logger.info(f"Run ID: {run_id}")
    logger.info(f"Task ID: {run.task_id}")

    if not run or not run.task_id:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Task not found")

    task_id = run.task_id
    celery_task = AsyncResult(task_id)
    task_state = celery_task.state
    logger.info(f"Task state: {task_state}")

    if task_state in ['SUCCESS', 'FAILURE', 'REVOKED']:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"Task already {task_state.lower()}")
    elif task_state in ['PENDING', 'STARTED', 'PROGRESS']:
        logger.info(f"Task state is {task_state}")
        
        # Revoke the task
        celery_task.revoke(terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')
        
        # Retrieve the subprocess_id from the task's info
        meta = celery_task.info
        subprocess_id = None
        
        if meta and 'subprocess_id' in meta:
            subprocess_id = meta['subprocess_id']
            logger.info(f"Subprocess ID found in task info: {subprocess_id}")
        else:
            logger.error("Subprocess ID not found in task info")

        if subprocess_id:
            os.kill(os.getpid(subprocess_id), signal.SIGUSR1)
            logger.info(f"Subprocess with ID {subprocess_id} terminated.")
        else:
            logger.error("Failed to terminate subprocess. ID not found.")

        update_data = {
            "status": "stopped",
            "status_description": "The task was stopped by the user",
            "finished_at": datetime.now()
        }
        await patch_run(run_id, update_data)
        return {"message": "Task stopped successfully"}
    else:
        return {"message": "Task NOT stopped successfully"}


From os.kill documentation, you can just pass the process id to kill the process.
os.kill(subprocess_id, signal.SIGTERM) #or signal.SIGKILL 

Or you can use psutil library to get the process using the pid and then kill it
process = psutil.Process(pid)
process.terminate()

or
process.kill()


Dear @andychukse,
i am using -> os.kill(subprocess_id, signal.SIGTERM).
Error Message:
INFO:routes.run:Subprocess ID found in task info: 15
ERROR:routes.run:Failed to terminate subprocess with ID 15. Process does not exist.
Context: I have a Celery worker task that spawns a subprocess (scrapy crawl) and I'm storing its PID (subprocess_id) in the task's metadata using self.update_state.
Question: Is this the correct approach for storing and managing subprocess IDs within a Celery worker task?
Please help me understand what's going wrong and how to manage subprocess IDs.

You can store and retrieve information in task's metadata. You said the subprocess is still running but shows process doesn't exist when you call os.skill? Confirm that you're using the correct celery task_id to retrieve the task especially if you have multiple task running. Try running the script and manually killing the subprocess from shell after starting.
For storing the pid of the subprocess, you can also try storing in a cache with the task_id as key, immediately after creating the process.

The requirement is that we do not want to save the celery pid. it would be deal runtime. When the PID is stored in the meta and received at the Run/{run. id}Stop endpoint, it must Kill the subprocess. But it's not working as we expected ?
